# Check interval between datetimes in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a field in database that has type of datetime in which I add time when user visit a page. When user again comes I want to check the interval between his first visit and current. If it is less or equal to 1 hour then I want to show him some message.
I store time like this

```
2011-03-04 00:25:01
```

The thing that I want to ask that how to check the interval in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have PHP >= 5.3 you can use [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) objects and functions:

```
$visit = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2011-03-04 00:25:01');
$now = new DateTime("now");

$diff = $now->diff($visit);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
SELECT COUNT(@UserID) FROM table WHERE LastVisit > (DateADD(now(),interval -1 Hour))
```

you can then check the count

Edit: added FROM clause

Comment: Is this for MySQL ? Isn't a FROM clause missing ?

Comment: Oh yea, time to go to bed now.

Comment: hi i dont need mysql function. I am asking for php function

Answer (score 1):

What you can so is, retrieve the the datetime, store it in a variable.
Create a var with time().

You can then convert the db datetime to a timestring using strtotime()

Subtract the datetime timestring from the new time. That should give you a difference in seconds. You can then manipulate your values and do the relevant checks.

$db = datetime_from_database;

$now = time();

$last = strtotime($db);

$diff = $now - $last; //this is in seconds

You can do something like

$minutes = $diff / 60;

If ($minutes > 60) echo 'more than 1 hour; 60 minutes';

Just work in it.

You can then use the date functions to format the new datetime using the $now and update the database.